# Runner is undefined in query of Knex.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, knex.js

I tried to use Knex.js on Node.js by following code:

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");
var knex = require("knex")({  
    client: 'pg',
    user     : 'username',
    database : 'database',
    password: "password",
    migrations: {
        tableName: 'knex_migrations'
    },
    pool: {
        min: 0,
        max: 7
    }
});

knex.select("*").from("users").then(function(rows){
    console.log(rows);
});
```

But, it threw an error about `Runner` object as follows:

```
/path/to/myapp/node_modules/knex/lib/interface.js:27
    return new Runner(this).run().then(onFulfilled, onRejected);
           ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at QueryBuilder_PG.Target.then (/path/to/myapp/node_modules/knex/lib/interface.js:27:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/path/to/myapp/test.js:14:32)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3
```

When I try to use `stream`, `pipe`, `exec` and `transaction`, same error occurred.
Please tell me how to solve this problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was really careless about configuration of client.
I have mistaken in description of "connection". It have to be written as follows:

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");
var knex = require("knex")({
    client: 'pg',
    connection: {
        host     : '127.0.0.1',
        user: 'username',
        database: 'database',
        password: 'password'
    },
    migrations:{
        tableName:"knex_migrations"
    },
    pool: {
        min: 0,
        max: 7
    }
});

knex.select("*").from("users").then(function(rows){
    console.log(rows);
});
```

It works with no problems.
Thank you!